# How to manage Weblogic 12c components with systemd?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, systemd

I want to manage Weblogic 12c components with systemd, but not sure about the expected behavior.

currently I have 3 units:

. adminserver `Type=simple`

. nodemanager `Type=simple`

. managedserver `Type=oneshot`

Question is:

1. if nodemanager killed, systemd should restart nodemanager and managedserver?
2. if managedserver killed, systemd should restart managedserver only?

OS: Red Hat 7

Comment: Always use the nodemanager to start/stop your instances (managed servers and admin server)
1. The nodemanager should be started when the host starts
2. If the nodemanager has started crashed instances it will try to restart them. Systemd is not needed.

Comment: thnx, but there are also other applications and we want to manage all of them in a unified way with systemd.

Answer (score -1):

This components is not managed by the OS. They run on java virtual machine. You can define some scripts to manage java processes (nodemanager, managed servers). But I think it is not good idea.

1) Managedservers is not affected of nodemanager process shutdown. In this case systemd can start nodemanager only.

2) Yes.